# How do I specify for a name in python?

Tags: python

```
a = input("Enter Your Name (a): ")
c = input("Enter Your Name (c): ")
if a == " Bob " :
    print ( " Happy " )
if c ==  " Joe "  :
   print ( " Anniversary " ) 
else :
   print ( " " )
```

Please help because I really need this help If any of ya'll can that would be great thanks to whoever does it!!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  "How do I specify for a name" isn't a sufficiently clear explanation and it's also not clear from the code what you're trying to do that's not exactly what the code is already doing.

Comment: `" Bob "` has spaces in it, so it won't match just Bob without spaces. Also, as pointed out, kindly make your question more clear.

Comment: Thank you guys for being so good